# Is it possible to hurt / Repel Demons and Ghosts with Really Salty Water

Tags: demons, ghosts

I have been watching Supernatural and other shows that include demons is it possible for salty water to effect demon, Ghost etc. or is it just grain of salt?

Comment: In which mythology are you asking.  The answer will vary from culture to culture.  A television programme is merely entertainment and cannot be taken as an accurate representation of any one particular mythology.

Answer (score 2):

In certain Christian traditions, [holy water is a mixture of salt and water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blessed_salt_in_Christianity) that has been blessed by a priest. Witches, vampires, and other nasty evil creatures were considered violently allergic to holy water. In the middle ages, due to the demand, there was even a delivery service for holy water in cities, like the milkman in the 20th century.

Comment: This would benefit from a citation.